# Player(Snake) does not move with consistency, stops moving

Tags: java, logic

I am working on a snake game and have just finished implementing KeyEvent and move method for my snake, which first starts with one segment. The snake responds to the first couple keys but then stops responding and continues moving according to last key input(that it actually responded to). Here is the code relevant to the question:

```
public class Snake implements Runnable, KeyListener {

private boolean running=false;
private Thread thread;

private BufferStrategy bs;
private Graphics g;

private int interval;

private ArrayList<Point> coords;

private LinkedList<Point> snake;
private boolean moveLeft;
private boolean moveRight;
private boolean moveUp;
private boolean moveDown;
private Point apple;

private void init() {

    display = new Display(title, width, height);
    display.getFrame().addKeyListener(this);

    initInterval(30);
    initPoints();
    initSnake();
    apple();
}

private void update() {

    moveSnake();

}

private void render() {
    bs = display.getCanvas().getBufferStrategy();
    if (bs==null) {
        display.getCanvas().createBufferStrategy(3);
        return;
    }
    g = bs.getDrawGraphics();
    //Clear Screen before drawing
    g.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
    //Draw here

    //Background
    g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);

    drawGrid();

    try {
        thread.sleep(100);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    drawSnake();
    drawApple();

    //End Drawing
    bs.show();  
    g.dispose();
}

private void initPoints() {

    coords = new ArrayList<Point>();

    for (int y=interval/2; y<=height-interval; y+=interval) {
        for (int x=interval/2; x<=width; x+=interval) {
            coords.add(new Point(x, y));
        }
    }
} 

private void initSnake() {

    snake = new LinkedList<Point>();
    int randPos = (int)( Math.random() * coords.size()-1 );
    snake.add( new Point( (int)coords.get(randPos).getX(), (int)coords.get(randPos).getY() ) );

}

private void drawSnake() {

    g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);

    for (int i = 0; i<snake.size(); i++) {
        fillRect((int)snake.get(i).getX(), (int)snake.get(i).getY(), interval, interval);
    }

}

private void moveSnake() {

    int headX = (int)snake.get(0).getX();
    int headY = (int)snake.get(0).getY();

    if (moveUp) {

        if (snake.size()==1) 
            snake.get(0).move(headX, headY - interval);


        else if (snake.size()>1) {              
            snake.addFirst( new Point(headX, headY - interval) );
        }

    }

    else if (moveLeft) {

        if (snake.size()==1) 
            snake.get(0).move(headX-interval, headY);

        else if (snake.size()>1) {
            snake.addFirst( new Point(headX-interval, headY) );
        }

    }

    else if (moveDown) {

        if (snake.size()==1) 
            snake.get(0).move(headX, headY + interval);

        else if (snake.size()>1) {
            snake.addFirst( new Point(headX, headY+interval) );
        }

    }

    else if (moveRight) {

        if (snake.size()==1) 
            snake.get(0).move(headX+interval, headY);

        else if (snake.size()>1) {
            snake.addFirst( new Point(headX+interval, headY) );
        }

    }

}

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

        switch (e.getKeyCode()) {

        case KeyEvent.VK_W :
            moveUp = true;
            break;
        case KeyEvent.VK_UP :
            moveUp = true;
            break;

        case KeyEvent.VK_A :
            moveLeft = true;
            break;
        case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT :
            moveLeft = true;
            break;

        case KeyEvent.VK_S :
            moveDown = true;
            break;
        case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN :
            moveDown = true;
            break;

        case KeyEvent.VK_D :
            moveRight = true;
            break;
        case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT :
            moveRight = true;
            break;
        default : break;
    }

    }

public void run() {

    init();

    while(running) {

            update();
            render();

    }

    stop();
}
```

***Unnecessary code has been snipped out including KeyListener implementation**

I am thinking the problem might be in moveSnake() or keyPressed(), i'm not sure though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way that the snake's directions is stored allows for multiple directions to have a true value, and can let the snake be pointing in multiple directions at the same time.

When the program sets the direction in the key event, it doesn't set the other directions to false so after several turns, the snake is pointing multiple ways at once. Having each turn set the other directions to false would be one way to fix this.

As a design strategy, representing your direction as a String constant can remove problems with snakes pointing multiple ways at once since you're direction will always be exactly one of 4 possible directions:

```
String UP = "up"
String LEFT = "left"
String RIGHT = "right"
String DOWN = "down"

String direction = RIGHT

// for key event processing, set the direction to your constants
case KeyEvent.VK_W :
        direction = UP;
        break;
...

if (direction.equals(UP)) {
     //code for moving up
}
```

If you want to do some digging, fiddling around with Java Enums gives you a more sophisticated way to do the same thing

Comment: I tried setting all other booleans to false in one if-block, but that didn't work. This idea did though, thanks for the help.